# Cloudera Certification for Hadoop developer

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

I want to write Cloudera certification for Hadoop developer as people suggested that it is more complex compared to Hortonworks certification.

I was looking for materials for my preparation. All the materials in Cloudera site is very expensive atleast for me. Can you please let me know the books which I can use to clear this certification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the content well in the following books, then you should be decently prepared to attempt the exam:

[Hadoop: The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/0636920021773.do)

[Hadoop Operations](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/mobile/0636920025085.do)

Answer (score 0):

I am also planning to write CCA Spark and Hadoop Developer Exam (CCA175) this year.

Kindly find my steps of preparation:

1. [Haddop: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491901632)
2. [Pro Apache Hadoop](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430248637)
3. [Hands on Practice by following youtube channel by itversity](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLf0swTFhTI8rJvGpOp-LujOcpk-Rlz-yE)

   Kindly add if you find more useful references.